# How to find out why MySQL crashed?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

My DB crashed today and this is what I see in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

```
2022-11-14T16:55:20.879027Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 288116
2022-11-14T16:55:20.889262Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-11-14T16:57:25.957099Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-11-14T16:57:26.248124Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-11-14T16:57:26.248154Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-11-14T16:57:26.285735Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-11-14T16:57:26.286101Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
```

Nothing else. There is also an empty `error.log.1` file there.

How can I find out why it crashed?

Comment: How do you know it crashed?

Comment: Because for 3 minutes my app was throwing endless errors like `Connection is not available, request timed out after 10001ms` or `Communications link failure`

Comment: Well, that only indicates a communication link failure, doesn't it.

Comment: Yes, but it happened at the same time that my logs above say `mysql starting as process 288116`. This is a DB which is supposed to be up all the time.

Comment: You can also check by running the SQL query: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'Uptime';` It returns the seconds since the last restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would look in the MySQL Server error log before the startup messages. If there was a reason logged, it will show that. For example, MySQL Server can shut itself down if there was a code assertion failure. The log usually tells you "an assertion occurred" and then outputs a screenful of diagnostic information, including a stack trace of the assertion.

But there may not be any message logged, if the restart was caused by something so sudden that MySQL Server could not log it.

For example if someone issued a `kill -9` against the `mysqld` process, that would cause the process to abort before it could log anything. It would be restarted automatically, but there would be no log explaining.

Another possible cause: the operating system might have restarted. Try to check the time of the last OS boot with the `uptime` shell command. Does that match the startup time of MySQL Server? (likely MySQL Server started within a minute or two of the OS startup)

Or the OS may be configured to respond when too much RAM is allocated by user processes, and it forcibly terminates the process using the most RAM. This is the "out of memory killer" or "OOM" feature of Linux for example. You may be able to see evidence of this happening in /var/log/messages. See https://haydenjames.io/how-to-diagnose-oom-errors-on-linux-systems/

Comment: Thanks. Found this in `syslog`: `Nov 14 16:55:19 solidinbox kernel: [925602.652695] Out of memory: Killed process 127869 (mysqld) total-vm:16366788kB, anon-rss:15537916kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:112 pgtables:31028kB            oom_score_adj:0`

Comment: Yes, that's not unusual. MySQL Server allocates a lot of RAM, and also there may be other processes on the same server consuming RAM. It's up to you to plan memory usage by all applications and services, so even at peak load they don't allocate more RAM than you have on the server.